# php-cs-fixer from symfony command

Tags: php, symfony, php-cs-fixer

I want to create a command that runs **php-cs-fixer fix src/AppBundle --rules=@Symfony**

I need it as a command to be able to pass some parameters to it like *--path* or *--rules*.

I know how to build a command, but I don't know how to run php cs fixer from it.
Can anyone provide some guidance?

LE: not needed anymore since I choose other solution to resolve my problem

Comment: Is this still relevant? I might prepare an example for you, but It would take me some time, so I rather ask first :)

Comment: I gave up on this and choose other solution. Thanks!

Comment: I see, thanks for update. Could you close this question, answer by your own or choose a solution, so people know it's been resolved? It would be much appreciated, since there is no way to find out it's on or resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Will the parameters change on every call, or often? If not, or there is only a small number of variations, I put it into one or more shell scripts, or a Makefile.

Even if the path will occasionally change, extracting the relevant path to a variable makes it easier to find, and change - just like setting a constant in your PHP code.

```
#!/bin/sh
# file: fixPhpStyles.sh

SRCPATH=src/AppBundle
/usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer fix $SRCPATH --rules=@Symfony
```